# Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS - Not able to adjust brightness

Tags: 22.04, brightness, xrandr

Since the update to Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS I am not able to adjust the brightness of my screens anymore.

- I was using the Brightness Controller before, but it doesn't work
  anymore.
- I have no brightness switch on the system menu
- I already tried using xrandr:

  xrandr | grep " connected" | cut -f1 -d " "

Gives me back:

```
XWAYLAND0 connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 530mm x 300mm
XWAYLAND1 connected 1920x1080+1920+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 530mm x 300mm
```

And after that:

`xrandr --output XWAYLAND0 --brightness 0.5`

But there is no visible change at all.

Comment: xrandr won't work because you're using Wayland. To confirm: you updated from 20.04? 20.04 defaulted to xorg for displays; 22.04 defaults to Wayland.

Comment: Yes right. There is no way to change brightness in wayland?

Comment: can you not change the brightness in the monitors themselves? or is one a laptop screen?

Comment: it's already almost on lowest level. and I use dual-boot so brightness controller was an easy way to adjust for ubuntu. I can manage it directly on the screen in the future. But I wonder why some basic option like this is not part of ubuntu anymore.

Comment: if you absolutely require this feature, you can switch back to xorg instead of wayland. Or look at [this xrandr replacement for wayland](https://github.com/maxwellainatchi/gnome-randr-rust/tree/adjust-brightness) which has an experimental branch that enables adjusting brightness

Comment: To be clear: most OSes don't allow adjusting brightness except for laptops; regular monitors can have brightness adjusted using buttons. `xrandr` adjust brightness using a "hack" that adjusts gamma for all channels equally, which looks like a less-bright screen. The tool I linked above aims to replicate this, but only works when you don't already have gamma adjustments (like nightshift) running.

Comment: also look at this tool https://github.com/zb3/gnome-gamma-tool

Comment: My eyes are thanking you very much for your help. The gnome-gamma tool provides what I need. I will test it a bit and also have a look at the xrandr replacement.

Answer (score 0):

Finally found a way to reduce brightness using `ddcutil` based on the [wiki here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/backlight).

Mine complained first that it can't get a valid response `!!! Unable to get capabilities for monitor on Display_Handle`

However the `getvcp` and `setvcp` commands worked!

Answer (score 0):

hope I am not late to suggest on this issue!
I am also facing same problem ever since I cleaned my laptop (Ubuntu 22.04.2) panel port by disassembling the laptop. I am pretty sure this is a software problem, not hardware (at least in my case). ANyway, I happen to know a cure of this problem for Ub-22.04.1.

1. In Terminal:: **sudo gedit /etc/modprobe.d/framework-als-blacklist.conf**
2. A blank gedit doc opens, write this command in here and save it:: **blacklist hid-sensor-hub**
3. After closing the gedit, return to Terminal and type:: **sudo update-initramfs -u**
4. In Terminal after this command execution:: **sudo reboot** .

This will most probably cure the problem, however if it dosen't please let us know! Additionaly, in the case you dont have *gedit* text editor preinstalled, you will face an error message in Terminal, there follow this step to install *gedit* and then execute the above mentioned steps:: **sudo apt  install gedit** .

Comment: Unless you had this issue before you messed with the hardware. I suggest it is a hardware issue.

Comment: It would be nice to explain what these commands actually are, and what they actually do. Otherwise I'm hesitant to just go ahead and run them in ignorance.

Answer (score 0):

1. Open the Software & Updates application window.
2. Select the Additional Drivers tab.
3. Choose any proprietary NVIDIA driver or one from your respective vendor. The higher the driver number, the more recent the version.

This is likely to improve your computer’s performance compared to using x.org’s drivers and may solve the brightness issue.

Comment: This is a sleazy way of choosing the proprietary NVIDIA driver. It's better to let Ubuntu choose the most compatible proprietary NVIDIA driver automatically.

Comment: @karel `ubuntu-drivers devices` shows recommended drivers. Then you can proceed manually if needed.

Answer (score -1):

What's the graphic driver you are using? Search "Additional Driver" in ubuntu and change the driver if it's using the default x.org driver.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).